# python hvac library - how to read secret from vault

Tags: python-3.x, hashicorp-vault

I am trying to read a secret from vault using hvac lib.
I am authenticated successfully with token.
My code:

```
import hvac
import os

f = open('/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token')
jwt = f.read()
client = hvac.Client(url='https://vault.domain.com', verify='/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt')
client.auth_kubernetes("namespace1", jwt)
print(client.is_authenticated())
```

yields in nice:

```
True
```

But if I add section for reading the secret:

```
response = client.kv.v1.read_secret(path='path/admin_pass')
```

I get 403 Forbidden

```
    raise exceptions.Forbidden(message, errors=errors, method=method, url=url)
hvac.exceptions.Forbidden: 1 error occurred:
    * permission denied

, on get https://vault.domain.com/v1/secret/path/admin_pass
```

I wonder why, as this path is given rights

```
path "path/admin_pass" {
  capabilities = ["read","list"]
}
```

What is a bit strange that url used by hvac is somewhat different than the one in the webUI of vault:

WebUI:

```
https://vault.domain.com/ui/vault/path/show/admin_pass
```

Python HVAC:

```
https://vault.domain.com/v1/secret/path/admin_pass
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Your acl needs to include the secret engine path: `secret/`, assuming your key/value secrets engine is mounted to `secret` (which is the default)

In addition to the **secret mount** - when it comes to acl's, `/data` must be added before the actual path.

Usually you also want to allow access to `secret/metadata/...` as well
This allows the path to be listed

```
path "secret/data/path/admin_pass" {
  capabilities = ["read","list"]
}
```

Comment: Hello I have just tried using this code but still getting error. Any idea how to solve this? 

 import hvac
client = hvac.Client(url='vault.abc.com:1100/')
response = client.secrets.kv.v2.read_secret_version(path='/secrets/secret/show/ab/ss/dd') 


 Error- raise_for_error raise exceptions.Forbidden(message, errors=errors, method=method, url=url) hvac.exceptions.
 Forbidden: 1 error occurred: * permission denied

Comment: Your permission path would be `secrets/data/secret/show/ab/ss/dd` in the example you posted @NIMI - did you create a policy for this path?